# PHP execution times takes like timer: 37.1496469975 seconds

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Some times PHP execution takes 37.1496469975 seconds. in the same script that sometimes execute in only 0.0846960544586 seconds. how could i fix that ?? is a problem of my php scripts or server optimizacion?? maybe the mysql server is made it slow.

does anyone could help me??

Comment: You should provide much more information for this...

Comment: Without some more details on what your script is doing, no-one can possibly answer that.

Comment: how could i upload a file here?

Comment: You don't. Copy and paste only the relevant bits, and indent it all 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to profile your code.

Try using [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler7), If that is too daunting, you can `echo time()` at points all through your code. When the request takes 30 seconds, you will clearly see what block it is happening at. Narrow it down untill you figure it out.

You can also check the mysql slow query log.

Comment: the funny thinks is that it only happen at production server

Comment: and there is no special activity that might take CPU resource?

Comment: Then try doing a log to a file instead of writing to the console. If you don't do some sort of profiling, you are shooting in the dark and really wasting time. I'd check the slow query log in mysql on production. You could have a race condition.

Comment: no there are no special activity, just a long query, and as i say on my question body, somethinks it only takes 0.08 seconds, but when i reload the page it makes that script run slow and them for a log period every page request are slow. i'll try to use the xdebug for debug performance. any way i have already optimize the mysql query consult with explain and i'm implementing the memcached.

Comment: if you have sometime to view this: app.promls.net, it only load a html so it does not take too much time to execute. i have a  microtime execution on index

Comment: by the way is there a way to profile php from console with out using xdebug

Answer (score 0):

The next step you need to take is to find out how long the different parts of your PHP code are taking to execute.  Then narrow down the scope of what you're timing as you find the parts that are taking the most time.  Eventually you will reach particular operations, like a MySQL query or an HTTP retrieval, that are taking unusually large or variable amounts of time.  Then you know what's actually going on with your script.

Comment: yeah, i'm going to debug my app using xdebug for know to see what can i optimize.